# If one of two function sequences converges, and the product converges, does the other sequence converge too?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f_n$ and $g_n$ be two sequences of functions. Also, $f_n.g_n$  converges to $f.g$ and $g_n$  converges to $g$. Can we prove $f_n$  converges to $f$? How?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What if $g$ and the functions $g_n$ are all identically $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Not without some restrictions. Let $f_n=(-1)^n$, $g_n=1/n$, $g=0$, $f=2$. Then
$$
g_n\to f,\ \ f_ng_n\to fg,
$$
but $f_n$ does not converge at all.

Now, if $g$ always far from zero and $\{f_n\}$ is bounded, then
$$
|f_n-f|=\frac1{|g|}\,|gf_n-gf|\leq\frac1{|g|}\,|g-g_n|\,|f_n|+\frac1{|g|}\,|g_nf_n-gf|\to0.
$$